# A long day for the unravelling Salesman

Tags: pattern

> MEMAUSABQSLCHLNBISSTPORDCPSMEM

It's been a long day.  How many beers did he drink?

Edit: Changed ASQ to AUS.  Sorry folks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

written like this

> MEM AUS ABQ SLC HLN BIS STP ORD CPS MEM

it can be seen that

> Those are airport codes: Memphis, Austin, Albuquerque, Salt Lake City, Helena, Bismarck ND, Holman Field, Chicago Ohare, St. Louis Downtown, and back to Memphis like all good traveling salesmen.

I count

> 9 hops,  that's a lot of hops (based alcoholic beverage) to consume, no wonder he's unraveling

map:

> https://www.google.com/maps/dir/MEM+airport/AUS+airport/ABQ+airport/SLC+airport/HLN+airport/BIS+airport/STP+airport/ORD+airport/CPS+airport/MEM+airport

Comment: Mostly there, but not quite.  See the "pattern" tag?

Comment: are you sure ASQ is correct, no travling salesman takes a longer route than neccessary,  perhaps you mean AUS?

Comment: Oh, you're good.  Yes, that's a mistake, it should be AUS.  I copied down the wrong Austin.  I'm sorry about that.  I'll fix the question.

Comment: Well that should make it clearer now.

Comment: I see a shield shape when I plot a map, but that doesn't suggest anything to me.

Comment: I've misled you around enough - that shield shape is intended to be reminiscent of a big zero, or at least not any other number.  Getting one of the points wrong didn't help.  Nice work!  I'll be a bit more careful next time.